# how discover during developing time from bottom to up the java hierarchy with files generated by jaxb

Tags: eclipse, web-services, xsd, xml-parsing, jaxb

Context: I am developing a client which will consume cxf soap webservice. At this moment, I only have the wsdl and its xsd's which are enough for generating the java types.

Requirement: I have to get the ContactType and I am sure we will receive it when the webservice be up-and-running (ContactType is just one sample among several others).

I searched in Eclipse by ContactType.java and I found it

```
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "ContactType", propOrder = {
        "telefoonnummer",
        "faxnummer",
        "gsm",
        "email",
        "website"
    })
    public class ContactType {

        @XmlElement(name = "Telefoonnummer")
        protected TekstKort20Type telefoonnummer;
...
        @XmlElement(name = "Email")
        protected Tekst20Type email;
        @XmlElement(name = "Website")
        protected Tekst20Type website;
    ...
```

The problem: I can't figure out which class consume it in order to code like MyWebServiceResponse.getMyAType().getMyBType.. so on until ContactType. It would be easy if the xsd tree was small or I know previously the model design (which isn't my reality).

Well, I know the type I will receive from webservices (let's called here getMyAType) and I can browse/navigate each object but it become a tremendous task done by eyes untill I found it one I have to read and populate a local pojo.

Doubt: why don't I find anywhere some code consuming/compsing ContactType? I manually searched by contact and I found:

```
@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {
...
    public OndernemingMyCostumerAppType createOndernemingMyCostumerAppType() {
        return new OndernemingMyCostumerAppType();
    }
...

        <xs:complexType name="OndernemingMyCostumerAppType">
            <xs:sequence>
    ...
                <xs:element name="Contact" type="ContactType" minOccurs="0"/>
    ...
                </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
```

I believe that a factory is interfering in the Eclipse tool Type Hierarchy and Call Hierarchy so Eclipse can show me which classes depend on ContactType (this would make my work easy).

My question: certainly it is a kind of common problem and I don't think JAXB/CXF experienced developers have been looking by eyes. Is there some smarter way to discover from botom class to up the tree dependency?

PS.: I can't get a xml sample answer so I could print it and control+F easialy in notepad. The server isn't yet up-and-running but I already have the wsdl+xsds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably one of the most dummy question I have made but I really didn't find the answer anywhere before. Instead of "Type Hierarchy" or "Call Hierarchy" views, just searched by "References" is enough (don't forget to pick up generated_source folder). I hope this can help someone using Eclipse and creating a client to soap service someday.

[image]